# How to configure Haml's :markdown filter to use Redcarpet with options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, redcarpet

I'm using Rails 3.2.11, Haml 4.0 and Redcarpet 2.2.2.

I would like to configure Haml's `:markdown` filter to use Redcarpet with `with_toc_data: true`. In `ApplicationHelper` I tried defining:

```
def markdown(text)
  markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(with_toc_data: true))
  raw markdown.render(text.to_s)
end
```

Though content in `:markdown` gets rendered, but without TOC data. How do I alter how `:markdown` is parsed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s currently no way to pass options through to the filter engines in Haml. The best solution for now is probably to replace the existing `:markdown` filter with a new one that has the options you want.

Try adding something like this to an initializer:

```
module Haml::Filters

  remove_filter("Markdown") #remove the existing Markdown filter

  module Markdown

    include Haml::Filters::Base

    def render(text)
      Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(with_toc_data: true)).render(text)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: This should've worked, `autolink: true` works, but `with_toc_data: true` doesn't. I'm gonna rais an issue on Redcarpet to see if the problem is actually there.

Comment: Ok, `with_toc_data` is an option for creating renderers, I inserted it in the wrong place. This is in fact the correct answer. What now? Do I mark it as correct even though it technically doesn't work (my fault) or do you correct me that it should be `Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(with_toc_data: true)).render(text)`, **then** I approve it?

Comment: @matija I’ve updated the answer. I was just looking into it myself, and then came back to update it and saw your second comment.

Comment: @matija you should probably update your question too, so future visitors aren’t confused.